# Ejecutar un loop que actualice datos en la ventana grafica con tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy tratando de realizar una ventana grafica  que muestre si existe conectividad hacia DVRs y dependiendo del status cambie el background y texto de un item que se encuentra en un listbox.

Lo primero que hago es pintar la ventana con los datos tomados de un diccionario, después mando llamar a una función que se encargara de cambiar el background y texto. En este punto tengo dos problemas, el primero es que no cambia el background de la etiqueta pero tampoco me marca error con estas lineas `estatus.itemconfig(i,  {"bg":"grey"})`, no estoy seguro si el scope de la función no me permita alcanzar esa variable.

El segundo problema es que si acerco el mouse a la ventana grafica mientras se ejecuta esta función  se queda trabada, alguna idea de como hacer actualizar los items de las listbox sin que se quede pegada la ventana?

Aqui el codigo:

```
def revisaDVR():
    UnavailableStores = 0
    NoVPN = 0
    NoDVR = 0
    NoDNS = 0

    i = 0
    for element in Tiendas:

        VPN = element[4]
        DVR_IP = element[3]

        with open(os.devnull,  'w') as DEVNULL:
            try:
                subprocess.check_call(
                ['ping ',  '-n ',  '3',  VPN], 
                stdout=DEVNULL,   # suppress output
                stderr=DEVNULL
                )
                try:
                    subprocess.check_call(
                    ['ping ',  '-n ',  '3',  DVR_IP], 
                    stdout=DEVNULL,   # suppress output
                    stderr=DEVNULL
                    )
                    try:
                        s = socket.socket()
                        s.settimeout(10)
                        s.connect((element[1], element[2]))
                        print ("accesible por DNS, ")
                        estatus.itemconfig(i,  {"bg":"green"})
                    except socket.error as exc:
                        print ("no accesible por DNS, ")
                        estatus.itemconfig(i,  {"bg":"grey"})
                        UnavailableStores = UnavailableStores + 1
                        NoDNS = NoDNS + 1

                except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
                    print("DVR no responde, ")
                    UnavailableStores = UnavailableStores + 1
                    NoDVR = NoDVR + 1

            except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
                    try:
                        s = socket.socket()
                        s.settimeout(10)
                        s.connect((element[1], element[2]))
                        print ("accesible por DNS; NO VPN, ")
                    except socket.error as exc:
                        print ("no accesible por DNS; No VPN, ")
                        UnavailableStores = UnavailableStores + 1
                        NoDNS = NoDNS + 1

                    NoVPN = NoVPN + 1


        window.after(2000,  revisaDVR)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
window = Tk()
scrollbar = Scrollbar(window)
scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT,  fill = Y )

misTiendas = Listbox(window,  yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set )
estatus = Listbox(window,  yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set )


for tienda in Tiendas:
    misTiendas.insert(END,  tienda[0])
    estatus.insert(END,  "Revisando")

# estatus.itemconfig(1,  {"bg":"red"})

misTiendas.pack( side = LEFT,  fill = BOTH )
estatus.pack( side = LEFT,  fill = BOTH)
scrollbar.config( command = misTiendas.yview )

window.after(11000,  revisaDVR)
window.mainloop()
```